# Change URL with wildcard

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I don't know if The tittle suitable or not (sorry for that).
First, I have to tell you that I am very novice at javascript.

I want to make javascirpt that change URL and redirect it on click (create on boookmark bar).
The idea is to change URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/[12_random_aphanumeric]/?&th=[16_random_aphanumeric]&v=c&s=a

to

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/[16_random_aphanumeric]

for example Change:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/bv293r3qycgk/?&th=16032287bb796882&v=c&s=a

to

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/16032287bb796882

---

so I use "window.location.assign" like :

```
javascript: window.location.assign(window.location.toString().replace('*?&th=', 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/')); window.location.assign(window.location.toString().replace('&v=c&s=a', ' '));
```

and of course its not working.

I just don't know how to use [*] wildcard on it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace` supports no such thing as a "wildcard". What you are looking for is called a [*regular expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The `*` in regexp is called a [Kleene closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

```
gmailUrlRegex = /(https:\/\/mail\.google\.com\/mail\/u\/0)\/h\/[A-z0-9]{12}\/\?&th=([A-z0-9]{16}).*/;
location.href = location.href.replace(gmailUrlRegex, "$1/#all/$2");
```

Visualize regex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/eAkLwrgNQcuUCisN

```js
var input = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/bv293r3qycgk/?&th=16032287bb796882&v=c&s=a";
console.log(input.replace(/(https:\/\/mail\.google\.com\/mail\/u\/0)\/h\/[A-z0-9]{12}\/\?&th=([A-z0-9]{16}).*/, "$1/#all/$2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the `th` param and  concatenate to new path

```js
var str='https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1a2b3c4d5e6f/?&th=abcd1234abcd1234&v=c&s=a',
 th = str.match(/(th=[a-z0-9]{16})/i)[0],
 url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/' + th;

console.log(url)
```